# SQL SUM AND GROUP BY (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

Following Setup:

```
PredDate                    WtSumLoc
2017-02-16 00:00:00.000     1360.139000
2017-02-16 00:00:00.000     399.444000
2017-02-28 00:00:00.000     400.000000
2017-02-28 00:00:00.000     8231.046000
2017-02-28 00:00:00.000     400.000000
2017-03-01 00:00:00.000     1118.055000
2017-04-15 00:00:00.000     400.000000
2017-04-15 00:00:00.000     2488.699000
2017-04-28 00:00:00.000     1555.556000
2017-04-28 00:00:00.000     1555.252000
2017-06-30 00:00:00.000     432.704000
```

I try to sum and Group by this Table by doing:

```
SELECT

MONTH(PredDate) 'Month',
sum(WtSumLoc) as 'sum'

FROM Table

GROUP BY PredDate
ORDER BY Month
```

And i get the following result:

```
Month   sum
2       1759.583000
2       9031.046000
3       1118.055000
4       2888.699000
4       40.000000
4       3110.808000
6       432.704000
```

Why are those not grouped up? Where is this 40.000 coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're grouping by date thus receiving distinct dates, but outputing month of these dates - thus for two distinct dates in the same month you're receiving two distinct records.

You have to change your query to something like

```
SELECT

MONTH(PredDate) 'Month',
sum(WtSumLoc) as 'sum'

FROM Table

GROUP BY    MONTH(PredDate)
ORDER BY Month
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL compliant solution is to wrap the month extraction part up in a derived table, and `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select "Month", sum(WtSumLoc) as 'sum'
from
(
    SELECT MONTH(PredDate) 'Month', WtSumLoc
    FROM Table
) dt
GROUP BY "Month"
ORDER BY Month
```

ANSI SQL uses double quotes to delimit identifiers, e.g. `"Month"`. SQL Server does also support square brackets, like `[Month]`. Single quotes are for string literals.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT

MONTH(PredDate) 'Month',
sum(WtSumLoc) as 'sum'

FROM Table

GROUP BY MONTH(PredDate)
ORDER BY Month
```

You must also group it by MONTH(PredDate)